# On average, how much gold will you make for a Hell/Inferno Whimsyshire run?

Tags: diablo-iii

At 500,000 gold for the Hell staff—and reportedly 1,000,000 for the Inferno staff—it seems like this is an upgrade that needs to be thought through, so I was looking for solid data from people who have made a considerable number of Whimsyshire runs.

Start to finish—and not counting Auction House sales of rare items—how much gold do you typically make doing a Whimsyshire run on either Hell or Inferno difficulty?

Comment: I think there are other reasons besides pure profit to unlock Whimsyshire :)

Comment: Well, this doesn't completely answer the question, but doing one Normal run I can get 10-15k just selling everything I pick up to the vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing hell whimsy shire two days ago with a buddy after helping him pay for it.  We were hoping for drops that would be comparable to inferno act 1, but the highest level that drops for items is for level 59 characters.  The gold drops were more than a little disappointing when compared to act 1 inferno.  We didn't get 5 stacks before doing it, but we would wait for 5 stacks before opening the clouds and pots of gold...  Overall we were all making right around 20-22k a run, and a run taking about 15-20 minutes.

Needless to say after being forced to tank for 2 runs I finally left my group and went back to farming inferno act 1, lots more gold, items to sell on AH, and maybe even an upgrade o.0!

Inferno, should be worth it though, but I wouldn't worry about that till you can clear act 3 inferno...

Answer (score 3):

I did some experiments today on this.  My friend and I went in with an average of 40% Gold find and 80% Magic Find.

After 2 runs this is the average of what we were walking away with:

- 10 Blues
- 3 Yellows
- 3 Square Gems
- 2 Square Radiant Gems
- 17K Raw Gold

Based on my own experience, I would say doing an Act Hell III/IV Nephilim Buff run is better than Hell Ponies.  Not only is it incredibly boring, but you'll almost get the loot off of one Ponies run off of one act boss with full Nephilim Buff.

Of course the loot is relatively high for Hell, but as the other answer stated, nothing better than 59 gear.

Certainly not worth 500K.

Comment: Very helpful, thakn you!  If you do another 2 or three runs through and update this answer it would be super helpful and I'd totally hit the accept button of course.  Probably can't accept it as canonical with just 2 runs but very helpful nonetheless!